# Getting keyboard input horizontally?

Tags: java, string, input

Below is the expected output for a Java program.

```
Hello. What is your name? 
 Hi John! How old are you? 
 So you're 22 eh? That's not old at all! 
 How much do you make John?


 500.0! I hope that's per hour and not per year! LOL!
```

Expected input:
`John 22 500` ( I need to give inputs horizontally, not vertically).

So what changes do I need to make? Like any function `scanner.next()` instead of `nextLine()` shoudl be used or how?

Can you please tell what's wrong in my program?

```
public class Test2 {
   public static void main(String args[]) {

       Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
       Scanner inc = new Scanner(System.in);

       String xyz = scanner.nextLine();
       int age = in.nextInt();
       double cme = inc.nextInt();
       System.out.println("Hello.What is your name?");
       System.out.println("So you're "+age+"eh?That's not old at all!" );
       System.out.println("hi"+xyz+"!How old are you?");
       System.out.println("How much do you make"+xyz+"?");
       System.out.println(+cme+"!I hope that's per hour and not per year!LOL!");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the split function.

```
 String s = scanner.nextLine();
 String[] inputs = s.split(" ");
```

If the input is John 22 500 inputs will be equal to ["John","22","500"]

You can convert items 1 and 2 to ints by doing

```
int age=Integer.valueOf(inputs[1])
```

and

```
int pay = Integer.valueOf(inputs[2])
```